# Testing for a specific exception in MRUnit

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, mapper, mrunit

In TestNG (or JUnit), it's simple. Goes something like:

```
@Test(expectedExceptions = NullPointerException)
public void test() throws NullPointerException {
    String x = null;
    String y = "y";
    Assert.assertEquals(x.someMethod(), y);
}
```

Above test will pass since `String x` is `null` and a NullPointerException is thrown.

But in MRUnit, the assertion works differently. Following is a test method for a mapper class:

```
@Test(expectedExceptions = Data.InvalidDataException.class)
public void testFirstCatch() throws Exception {
    Data data = someData;
    MapDriver.newMapDriver(mapper)
        .withInput(new LongWritable(0), someData)
        .withOutput(someKey, NullWritable.get())
        .runTest();
```

It takes an input with `someData` and expects the output with `someKey`. But I need to cover a Try/Catch block where it checks for `someData`'s validity by feeding bad data. In this case, it seems like `.withOutput` method isn't even necessary. Is there a way in MRUnit to conveniently test for `Exceptions`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just had to do `.run();` instead of `.runTest();`. Hope this helps someone.